# SQL.Request method 

Tags: excel-2007, ado

can somebody tell me what's the equivalent of SQL.Request() method in excel 2007? It seems the add-in doesn't come built-in as part of excel versions after 2002.  What's the solution for this ??

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb257085.aspx), "It is recommended that you use the objects, methods, and properties in the **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects (ADO)** library instead of SQLRequest and the other ODBC functions in the Xlodbc.xla add-in."

You might find some helpful information here:

[How to transfer data from an ADO Recordset to Excel with automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246335)

[Using ADO with Excel Data Sources](http://blogs.msdn.com/frice/archive/2004/07/09/178563.aspx)